# Split string by two conditions - wildcard

Tags: python, string, split

I need to split a string by a charcter plus a wildcard character:

```
text1 = "CompanyA-XYZ-257999_31.12.2000"
text2 = "CompanyB-XYZ-057999_31.12.2000"
```

I want to split that string at the position [-2] or [-0], so right after XYZ. Since I have two "-", I can not simply split by that character. In fact i would like to have a split in the form [-AnyNumber], where AnyNumber should be a wildcard for an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex, you can split from the right using `str.rsplit`  setting `maxsplit` to 1:

```
text1 = "CompanyA-XYZ-257999_31.12.2000"

print(text1.rsplit("-",1))
['CompanyA-XYZ', '257999_31.12.2000']

text2 = "CompanyB-XYZ-057999_31.12.2000"
print(text2.rsplit("-",1))
['CompanyB-XYZ', '057999_31.12.2000']
```

If you want them stored in variables just unpack:

```
comp, dte = text2.rsplit("-",1)
print(comp,dte)
('CompanyB-XYZ', '057999_31.12.2000')
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this using `re`

```
import re
>>>re.findall("(.+XYZ)-(.+)",text1)
[('CompanyA-XYZ', '257999_31.12.2000')]
```

**or**

```
>>>re.findall("(.+)-(.+)",text1)
[('CompanyA-XYZ', '257999_31.12.2000')]
```

Comment: thats a good idea, can you tell me how do that if text would be text3 = "CompanyC-3552_31.12.2000"? is the "(.+)" in your code the wildcard?

Comment: simply `re.findall("(.+)-(.+)",text3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text1 = "CompanyA-XYZ-257999_31.12.2000"

>>> text1[:-18]
'CompanyA-XYZ'

>>> text1[-17:]
'257999_31.12.2000'
```

Answer (score 0):

split by `[-AnyNumber]`

```
In [5]: import re

In [6]: re.split('-(?:[0-9])', text1)
Out[6]: ['CompanyA-XYZ', '57999_31.12.2000']

In [7]: re.split('-(?:[0-9])', text2)
Out[7]: ['CompanyB-XYZ', '57999_31.12.2000']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex with a lookahead assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> text1 = "CompanyA-XYZ-257999_31.12.2000"
>>> text2 = "CompanyB-XYZ-057999_31.12.2000"
>>> re.split('-(?=\d)', text1)
['CompanyA-XYZ', '257999_31.12.2000']
>>> re.split('-(?=\d)', text2)
['CompanyB-XYZ', '057999_31.12.2000']
```