# remove only numbers between brackets from a string

Tags: python

I have strings, and I need to remove only numbers inside brackets (remove brackets too)
from this :

```
str = "1.25 (10), 1.5 (148), 1.25 (24)"
```

to this:

```
"1.25, 1.5, 1.25"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string by two conditions - wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536683/split-string-by-two-conditions-wildcard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

x = "1.25 (10), 1.5 (148), 1.25 (24)"

x=re.sub(r'\s*\(\d+\)\s*', '',x)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> x

1.25, 1.5, 1.25
```

Comment: Perhaps a quick explanation of the components of the regex would be helpful?

Comment: \s* implies one more whitespaces and \d+ implies at least one digit. So I hope with these you can understand the logic behind that expression. So whenever you find a substring with this form it replaces it (substring) with an empty string.

Comment: Cheers @Sai Screenivas - that's exactly it!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
str = "1.25 (10), 1.5 (148), 1.25 (24)"
a=[i for i in str.split(" ") if ("(" not in i)]
str=",".join(a)
print(str)
```

**Answer:**

```
1.25,1.5,1.25
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow

You can use regex like this:

```
import re
str = "1.25 (10), 1.5 (148), 1.25 (24)"
new_str = re.sub("\s\([0-9.]+\)", "", str)
```

The regex command looks for patterns starting with a space followed by a number inside a bracket and replaces it with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I tried by getting the brackets and items inside the it and thereafter remove it

---

```
import re

string = "1.25 (10), 1.5 (148), 1.25 (24)"
txt = string.split(',')
clear = ''
for i in txt:
    clear += re.sub('\(.*\)', '', i)

print(clear.replace('  ', ', '))
```